# Linq with where clause in many-to-many EF Code First object

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

In an MVC4 project, using code first, I have the following:

```
public class Course 
{
   public string CourseId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsActive { get; set; }

   public virtual Categories ICollection<Category> { get; set; }

   public Course()
   {
      Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
   }
}

public class Category
{
   public string CategoryId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual Courses ICollection<Course> { get; set; }

   public Category()
   {
      Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
   }
}
```

Code First then rightly creates an extra table for this relation, since it is many-to-many.

My problem is when I need a list of Categories with the active Courses (IsActive==true). This here, for example, is not possible:

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Courses.Where(y => y.IsActive)).ToList();
```

Any input how I get a list of the categories with only the active courses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This query will return all categories that have at least one course that is active:

```
var categories = db.Categories
    .Where(x => x.Courses.Any(y => y.IsActive))
    .ToList();
```

This query will return all categories whose courses are all active. If, for example, a category has two courses and one of the courses is inactive, that category will be excluded from the query:

```
var categories = db.Categories
    .Where(x => x.Courses.All(y => y.IsActive))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Tried it, and it includes all the ones where IsActive is false as well.

Comment: The query will include a category that has at least one course that is active. Do you want to exclude a category if it has at least one inactive course?

Comment: No, I want to see all the categories that have courses, but not include the courses that are inactive.